# How to connect Mendix to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, mendix

I'm just learning how to use Mendix and I'm running into a problem. I have a database that holds things such as Landing Zones, County, and Helicopter information. I can't seem to figure out how to connect my SQL Server database to the application. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @william-hodges, have you tried that https://world.mendix.com/display/refguide4/Configuration ?

Comment: What would the url path be for a on premises database running in sqlexpress?

Comment: @willam-hodges, have a read on that https://mxforum.mendix.com/questions/711/Does%20Mendix%20run%20on%20Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Express%20Edition?

Comment: I haven't but I will now. I literally just downloaded Mendix so it's all new. I'm used to writing all the code in c# and xaml lol

Comment: @willam-hodges ok matey

Comment: I read you post, but it didn't tell me much. I already have an established database, can I use mendix to access that on local sqlexpress?

Comment: @William, you are trying to get data from your sqlexpress instance? Or do you want to store your data there.

Comment: posted an answer below, so I could add screenshotd

Comment: If the other database is not intended as the primary Mendix app database, but you want to access it from Mendix, you can use the Database Connector from the Mendix Marketplace https://marketplace.mendix.com/link/component/2888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data from another database, you will have to use appservices or webservices.

Alternatively, you can connect your application to your MSSQL Database Settings -> Profile

[image]
[image]

Create entities in your domainmodel for the data, and import your data into the table using the sql tool of your preference ([SQL Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx))

This will work for static data. 
If the data is dynamic, you will need [webservices](https://world.mendix.com/display/refguide4/Call+Web+Service)

Read more on how to [import](https://world.mendix.com/display/refguide6/Imported+web+service) or [publish](https://world.mendix.com/display/refguide6/Published+Web+Services) a webservice

And here on consuming one

If the data are in another mendix application, you might need to [consume](https://world.mendix.com/display/refguide6/Consumed+App+Services) a [published](https://world.mendix.com/display/refguide6/Published+App+Service) appservice to do it.

Finally, you might get more feedback on the [Mendix forum](https://mxforum.mendix.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply!